# C++ unique_ptr as class property doesnt compile

Tags: visual-studio-2013, directx-11, unique-ptr

i'm using Visual Studio 2013 with the DirectXToolkit but i seem to not be able to compile the unique_ptr part:

```
class Graphics
{
private:
    ID3D11Device *Device;
    ID3D11DeviceContext *DeviceContext;
    IDXGISwapChain *SwapChain;
    ID3D11RenderTargetView *RenderTargetView;

protected:
    std::unique_ptr<PrimitiveBatch<VertexPositionColor>> Batch;
```

These are the errors:

1. Error   3   error C2974: 'std::unique_ptr' : invalid template argument for '_Ty', type expected
2. Error   5   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
3. Error   2   error C2065: 'VertexPositionColor' : undeclared identifier
4. Error   1   error C2065: 'PrimitiveBatch' : undeclared identifier   d Error 4   error C2059: syntax error : '>'

The Headers and libs are all included. The IDE itself doesnt show any error.

Maybe someone can tell me what i'm doing wrong! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh gosh, i had to include the using namespace in the same header as the class definition. this solved the errors.